# Copy cell content to clipboard RadGridView WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, radgridview

I'm working in `RadGridView` where i need to copy the cell content.

As part of the application functionality, i want the Grid `SelectionUnit` to always be of type `Row`. In addition to this, we also want to expose a mechanism where the user can select a cell value for copy to clipboard.

Is there a way to do this? For example, double clicking a cell copies the cell value where as single click always selects the row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

Not a perfect one, but for your requirement it suits.

```
void testGridView_CopyingCellClipboardContent(object sender, GridViewCellClipboardEventArgs e)
{
    if (grdName.CurrentCell != null && grdName.CurrentCell.Column == e.Cell.Column)
    {
        e.Cancel = false;
    }
    else
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Where replace your GridView name with "grdName".